# How to avoid micro lags while music is playing?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing Audio Player in Qt. I use QMediaPlayer. I tried to connect music position with `QSlider`, but when 2 connecting are working, it makes micro lags. That's my code:

```
connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged, this, [&](qint64 value){
    int pos = static_cast<int>(value);
    ui->positionSlider->setValue(pos);
});
connect(ui->positionSlider, &QSlider::valueChanged, this, [&](int value){
    player->setPosition(value);
});
```

How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if the [slider is pressed](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#sliderDown-prop) when the slider value changes.

If it's not pressed, it means it is just a progress event.

If it is pressed, then it means the user is interacting with it, therefore set the mediaplayer position

```
connect(ui->positionSlider, &QSlider::valueChanged, this, [&](int value)
{
    if (ui->positionSlider->isSliderDown())
        player->setPosition(value);
});
```

By the way, that's exactly what they do in the [reference example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-player-player-cpp.html).

Comment: It dosn't work. Methods like `sliderPressed()` return nothing. Their's type is `void`.

Comment: My bad sorry, the right method is isSliderDown(). I have updated my answer